# Need a input type for duration

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, input

I need to ask the user for a duration in a html input.

f.e. 03h 12m 12s

Is there any way to give him a selection, like input type date?

I use Bootstrap 4.

Thank you

Comment: I've published a js/HTML5 control to do this on npm [chronlyhms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chronlyhms) let me know what you think and feel free to contribute.  A demo is on CodePen [https://codepen.io/stephanluis/pen/oNqMBQa](https://codepen.io/stephanluis/pen/oNqMBQa).  Try it on Safari / iOS/ Android – it always looks and works the same on any device.

Comment: better for access from 'real devices' on Saucelabs or BrowserStack is CodeSandbox  [https://6s0mfy.csb.app/](https://6s0mfy.csb.app/) and [editable](https://codesandbox.io/embed/naughty-booth-6s0mfy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 10):

`<input type='number'>` set `min` and `max`

### Demo

```css
input,
label {
  font: inherit;
  width: 4ch;
}
```

```html
<form id='duration'>
  <input id='h' name='h' type='number' min='0' max='23'>
  <label for='h'>h</label>
  <input id='m' name='m' type='number' min='0' max='59'>
  <label for='m'>m</label>
  <input id='s' name='s' type='number' min='0' max='59'>
  <label for='s'>s</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is 5 years old, but your problem still does not have an answer.  (Here on SO or in HTML)!

Don't know why it's taking HTML standards so long to adopt a time as a 'base' unit input control.  So much effort has been spent on variations in clock type and world calendars that a simple countdown timer is hard to code!

I've just released a webcomponent input-duration to fix the situation:
NPM [input-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/input-duration), written in vanilla JS and works with or without JS bundling.

[`<INPUT-DURATION`> on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/input-duration)

```html
<input-duration id="bob"></input-duration><br>
 
<script type="module">
import id from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/input-duration/+esm'
</script>
```

[input-duration, full fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-waterfall-6mxpg2?file=/index.html)