# HTML5: input type duration

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Is there a way to use **input type duration**. I am trying to make a input in a way, a user to add time duration something like this `06:30:27:15 ( hh:mm:ss:ms )` and should allow only `(0-23:0-59:0-59:0-59)`.

any help appreciated!

**NOTE!:** I want to implement this in Angular2+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Need a input type for duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506366/need-a-input-type-for-duration)

Comment: Use [imaskjs](https://imask.js.org/)

Comment: I've published a js control to do this on npm [chronlyhms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chronlyhms) let me know what you think and feel free to contribute.

Comment: a demo is on CodePen [https://codepen.io/stephanluis/pen/oNqMBQa](https://codepen.io/stephanluis/pen/oNqMBQa)

Comment: better on CodeSandbox [https://6s0mfy.csb.app/](https://6s0mfy.csb.app/) and [editable](https://codesandbox.io/embed/naughty-booth-6s0mfy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Use [<INPUT-DURATION>](https://www.npmjs.com/package/input-duration) on NPM

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, neither HTML inputs nor JavaScript itself support a duration data type. `<input type="time">` is for a time of the day, and may display AM/PM selectors depending on your locale.

Your best bet is to work with a text input and to use JavaScript events to automatically insert `:` and ignore invalid inputs. Using the pattern attribute may also help. Be sure to convert the value to a number before using it from the JavaScript side of things. Here's something to get you started.

```js
{
  let durationIn = document.getElementById("duration-input");
  let resultP = document.getElementById("output");
  
  durationIn.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    resultP.textContent = "";
    durationIn.checkValidity();
  });
  
  durationIn.addEventListener("invalid", function (e) {
    resultP.textContent = "Invalid input";
  });
}
```

```css
input:invalid:not(:focus) { background: red; }
```

```html
<input id="duration-input" type="text" required pattern="[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}" value="00:00:00:00" title="Write a duration in the format hh:mm:ss:ms">

<p id="output"></p>
```

I'm sure there are many open-source libraries which provide a ready-made widget for that.

Comment: Obviously that's if you just want one input. Using four number inputs is absolutely viable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to implement this in Angular 9, How can I achieve this in Angular 9?

Comment: It's not trivial to do, and I have no experience with Angular, sorry.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe try something like this:

```
<input type="time" step="0.001">
```

Answer (score -6):

```
<label for="appt">Choose a time for your meeting:</label>

<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt"
       min="09:00" max="18:00" required>

<small>Office hours are 9am to 6pm</small>
```

Try this... I hope this helps !
This is something I did for one of my projets...

Comment: A time input is for a time of the day, not a duration. Browsers may show an AM/PM selector if the user's local uses a 12h clock, and the maximum value will be 23:59:59.