# What's wrong with this localtime in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring + Thymeleaf project Here is the description in essence:

```
@Entity
public class CarEntity {
...
    @Column(name = "time_oot", nullable = false)
    //@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "hh:mm:ss")
    //@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm:ss")

    private LocalTime timeOut;
}
```

We read the time in localtime format from the HTML form. I had the output without seconds, everything worked. Ie form input was of this type:

```html
<label for="inputime">Время</label>
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputime" placeholder="Задайте время" max="0:50:00" min="0:00:01" value="00:00" th:field="*{timeOut}" required>
```

But i don't need hours on the form, just minutes and seconds, i added seconds on the form:

```html
<label for="inputime">Время</label>
<input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputime" placeholder="Задайте время" max="0:50:00" min="0:00:01" value="00:00:00" step="1" th:field="*{timeOut}" required>
```

And now the error began to fly out:

```
Field error in object 'CarEntity' on field 'timeOut': rejected value [00:12:25]; 
codes 
[typeMismatch.CarEntity.timeOut,typeMismatch.timeOut,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalTime,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [CarEntity.timeOut,timeOut]; 
arguments []; default message [timeOut]]; 
default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalTime' for property 'timeOut'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] 
to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.LocalTime] for value '00:12:25'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [00:12:25]]]
```

What is the problem?

i tried adding:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "hh:mm:ss")
```

or

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "hh:mm:ss")
```

The error still crashes:

```
"Parse attempt failed for value [01:11:23]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")`

You can test this via this:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("00:12:25", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
        System.out.println("localTime = " + localTime);
    }
}
```

When using `hh:mm:ss`, this code throws an Exception, when using `HH:mm:ss` it works. `HH` is what you need to use for 24h notation.

Comment: But i only need mm:ss. i don't need hh:mm. How do I do this? Or can this problem not be solved by conventional means?

Comment: `LocalTime` is an object that represents hours, minutes and seconds. Maybe you need [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) instead?

Comment: The main thing for me is to have seconds. Any way.

Comment: On the input form, the user must enter the time in minutes and seconds. The clock will always be set to 0.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065890/html5-input-type-duration the HTML input might display AM/PM indications. What you can do is use a `CarFormData` object that uses `String timeOut` and convert the `String` to `Duration` when converting the `CarFormData` to an actual `CarEntity` (and use a standard text input in the HTML).